# How to configure hippie-expand for emacs?

Tags: emacs

I would prefer that hippie-expand behaves more like the completion in Sublime. For example if I expand

```
As
```

I would like to get just

```
Assign
```

but hippie-expand gives me

```
Assign.new(:y, Add.new(Variable.new(:y), Number.new(3))))
```

Is it possible to change this ?

Comment: `hippie-expand` is like a box of chocolates - you never know what you're gonna get.
Better use `auto-complete-mode` or `helm` or `semantic` or whatever completion your mode
provides. Your code looks object-oriented-ish, you should be able to get better
completion than `hippie-expand`.

Answer (score 5):

Ok it seems as if the following does exactly what I want:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") (make-hippie-expand-function
                           '(try-expand-dabbrev-visible
                             try-expand-dabbrev
                             try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers) t))
```

Comment: Why not just use dabbrev?

Comment: Because I would like to expand filenames.